# How to split the data from a single row into multiple rows in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, split, sql-server-2014

I have a table in the following format

```
ProjectID           LocationID
1                   [1,2,3,4]
2                   [2,3]
```

Can I split the data in the column LocationID into multiple rows like below?

```
ProjectID           LocationID
1                   1
1                   2
1                   3
1                   4
2                   2
2                   3
```

I need to get the data loaded to Power-Bi using the SQL only.
is it possible?

Comment: What is your SQL Server version? It's a valid JSON array, so you may try to parse it using `OPENJSON`.

Comment: I actually want to get that data into powerbi. So, I need to formulate a query which works.

Comment: Please mention what's the data type of locationid  column and what's the version of your sql server.

Comment: The locationID column is of type NVarchar. SQL server version is 2014, but it doesnt matter because ill be using that query from the Power-Bi application.

Comment: Well, `SELECT v.ProjectID, j.LocationID FROM (VALUES (1, '[1,2,3,4]'), (2, '[2,3]')) v (ProjectID, LocationID) OUTER APPLY OPENJSON (v.LocationID) WITH (LocationID int '$') j` is an option.

Comment: @ thenewguy Why do you think version doesn't matter as PowerBi is the client? 2014 has no JSON support or inbuilt string split

Comment: Right now for development its a sql server 2014, but it will moved to Azure SQL server.

Comment: For development you should use something with more similar functionality than Azure Sql database then. 2019 would enable you to use newer language elements

Comment: Okay, could you please tell me how I can achieve that in SSMS 2019 version?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If data type of locationID is varchar then:

```
 create table projects (ProjectID int, LocationID varchar(50));
 insert into projects values(1,                  '[1,2,3,4]');
 insert into projects values(2,                  '[2,3]');
```

Query:

```
select projectid, value 
 from projects 
 CROSS APPLY STRING_SPLIT(replace(replace(locationid,'[',''),']',''),',')
```

Output:

| projectid | value |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 |
| 1 | 2 |
| 1 | 3 |
| 1 | 4 |
| 2 | 2 |
| 2 | 3 |

*db<fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=765060d2b08252fa07191a51f7dc2916)*

Solution for SQL Server 2014

```
 create table projects (ProjectID int, LocationID nvarchar(max));
 insert into projects values(1,                  '[1,2,3,4]');
 insert into projects values(2,                  '[2,3]');
```

Query:

```
     WITH tmp AS
(
    SELECT
        ProjectID,
        LEFT(replace(replace(locationid,'[',''),']',''), CHARINDEX(',', replace(replace(locationid,'[',''),']','') + ',') - 1) LocationID,
        STUFF(replace(replace(locationid,'[',''),']',''), 1, CHARINDEX(',', replace(replace(locationid,'[',''),']','') + ','), '') b
    FROM projects
    
    UNION all

    SELECT
        ProjectID,
        LEFT(b, CHARINDEX(',', b + ',') - 1),
        STUFF(b, 1, CHARINDEX(',', b + ','), '')
    FROM tmp
    WHERE
        b > ''
)

SELECT
    ProjectID, LocationID
FROM tmp
ORDER BY projectid
```

Output:

| ProjectID | LocationID |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 |
| 1 | 2 |
| 1 | 3 |
| 1 | 4 |
| 2 | 2 |
| 2 | 3 |

*db<fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2014&fiddle=b6de9005b18db04fd04cd3cf419ab6a4)*

Comment: Sorry, But I dont have the provision to create or alter the table. I need to fetch the data in the above said format using the select clause.

Comment: Since your sql server version is 2014 neither string_split() or openjson() will work. Let me find something else.

Comment: Could you please tell me how it can be done in a more recent version? Ill try thats since it will be moved to  Azure SQL database

Comment: What id did will work on 2016 and on ward versions. Now revising my answer for 2014.

Comment: WHERE
         b  ''    Im getting an error in this part of the query.

Comment: @the_new_guy sorry for the typo. I have revised my answer.

Answer (score 2):

In SQL Server 2014, you can use a recursive CTE -- which Kazi also proposes.  I think this is a slightly simpler version:

```
with cte as (
      select projectId, convert(varchar(max), null) as locationid,
             convert(varchar(max), substring(LocationId, 2, len(locationId) - 2)) + ',' as rest
      from t
      union all
      select projectId,
             left(rest, charindex(',', rest) - 1),
             stuff(rest, 1, charindex(',', rest), '')
      from cte
      where rest <> ''
     )
select projectid, locationid
from cte
where locationid is not null;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2014&fiddle=f16c7eb3c9fe50269ee638c242588087) is a db<>fiddle.

In particular, the anchor part just sets up the data -- it does not extract any elements from the string.  So, all the logic is in the recursive part, which I find easier to maintain.

Answer (score 1):

I used STRING_SPLIT() which is a table valued function supports SQL server 2016 and higher versions. You need to provide the formatted string into this function and use cross apply to join and generate the desired output.

```
SELECT
    projectID
   , REPLACE(REPLACE(locationId,'[',''),']','') as [locationid]  
INTO #temp_table
FROM split_string -- Add your table name here


SELECT 
    projectID
    ,VALUE [locationid]  
FROM     #temp_table
CROSS APPLY STRING_SPLIT( [locationid] , ',');
```

[image: Result]